# PHP authentication code to python

Tags: php, python, api

I am trying to use python to login to my bittrex account and set up an automatic trading bot (written by myself in python).

However my problem is that I cannot authenticate myself. There is an API document provided by bittrex, but the code is in PHP (and i really dont know PHP)...

The main problem is that I am was not involved so far in the hmac hash authentication... so I am kinda lost here.

The PHP code provided by bittrex is the following:

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

I also tried to make up something based on other stackoverflow posts... but all I could come up was this:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests
import time

apikey = 'xxx'
apisecret = 'xxx'


def request_comkort(url, payload ):
        tosign = "&".join( [i + '=' + payload[i] for i in payload] )
        sign = hmac.new( apisecret, tosign , hashlib.sha512);
        headers = {'sign': str(sign.hexdigest()), 'nonce': str(int(time.time())), 'apikey': apikey }
        r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        print tosign, '\n'
        print sign, '\n'
        print headers, '\n'
        print url, '\n'
        print payload, '\n'
        print headers, '\n'
        return r.text

print request_comkort("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances", {})
```

Unfortunately it doesn't really work.. 
I get error:

```
{"success":false,"message":"APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}
```

If someone could help me out or point me in the right direction, that would be awesome. I can hardly wait to run my trading bot...:)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: Check the network traces to assert any difference in your API request

Comment: I would do that if I knew how to do it. Sorry but my lack of knowledge requires more than one sentence hints. Sorry for my bad English failing to emphasize how dummy I am in this topic. I know some python but absolutely beginner in network stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and came up with this. 
Unfortunally I have passes the key and nonce problem but having issues with secret key. Not very familiar with encryption. If you can help...
Here is the code. Notice I{m using python 2.7 on ubuntu. so requests and urllib may work diferent to your version

```
enter code here
import json
import time
import hashlib
import hmac

nonce = str('{:10.0f}'.format(time.time()))
apikey = 'mykey'
apisecret = 'mysecret'


url = 'https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey=apikey'
url += '&nonce=' + str(int(time.time()))
sign = hmac.new(b'apisecret', b'url', hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
headers = {'&secret': sign}
request = requests.get(url, sign)
balance = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

print(balance)
```